# What's the best practice for working with nullable SQL data in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, casting, nullable

I tend to do this, for example a method that accepts an integer:

```
DoSomethingWithThisInt((int)dbObj.nullableInteger);
```

However I will also usually ensure that this code will never happen unless it has a value, sometimes this means I have to check for null first which takes more lines of code.

Is there a better way or am I doing this right by simply casting?

Comment: If you do not allow null values in your .net code, why not disallow null values in your database scheme (also)?

Comment: I think @Filip has a great point.  Is there a reason to maintain the ability to null the field in your database?  If not, might as well save yourself the headache and go non nullable all the way through.  Null tends to lead to evil shenanigans in the database even when intentionally used for that matter, I'd avoid it if you can.

Comment: @Filip De Vos in the thing I am working on now, I save parts of the object to the database at a time though various steps, so I need some to be nullable so I can write to the database initially, then when it's time to re-evaluate or edit the data it's ready to update with more data

Comment: So your data is Nullable in nature, or it needs sane defaults. If something goes wrong in the writing to the database you will have records with some fields containing null values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've already checked for null prior to the line of code in question, you can simply use

```
dbObj.nullableInteger.Value
```

As opposed to a cast.

If, for example, *default* values would also be sufficient (such as 0 for integers, false for booleans, etc.), then you can omit the null check and simply utilize

```
doObj.nullableInteger.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this. If it is null would .Value cause an error? Do the defaults come from the database table definition?

Comment: If it's `null` then yes, `.Value` would cause an error; you should expect it to do the same thing as the cast, since they compile to the same IL code. And no, the defaults are those given by `default(T)`, e.g. `default(int) == 0`, `default(bool) == false`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there are two choices for syntax. Either use the properties of the `Nullable<T>` type, like so:

```
if (dbObj.nullableInteger.HasValue)
{
    DoSomethingWithThisInt(dbObj.nullableInteger.Value);
}
```

or use the syntactic sugar provided by the C# language, which translates to the same thing:

```
if (dbObj.nullableInteger != null)
{
    DoSomethingWithThisInt((int)dbObj.nullableInteger);
}
```

Which one you use is just a matter of preference; personally I prefer the latter.